# How to assign values of C# variables to javascript variables inside update panel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Is is possible to update values of javascript inside the update panel
I am trying it in update panel so that the values get refreshed without postback

```
int used=50,unused=70;

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <script>
        var data = [{
            values: [<%Response.Write(unused);%>,<%Response.Write(used);%>],
            labels: ['Unused', 'Used '],
        }];

        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
    </script>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Try using `<%= ... %>` block like this: `values: [<%= unused %>, <%= used %>]`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried that but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Response.Write` (or `<%= unused %>`)  in an UpdatePanel. It will give the following error.

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.`

If you want the values of `unused` and `used` you better call the script directly in the method that updated the UpdatePanel

```
string scriptData = "Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', { values: [" + used + ", " + unused + "], labels: ['Unused', 'Used '] });";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "startPlot", scriptData, true);
```

Or create a script that takes the values of used and unused and trigger the plot from there.

```
string scriptData = "setPlotValues(" + used + ", " + unused + ");";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "startPlot", scriptData, true);
```